# pybind11 incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (arg0: _GstPadProbeInfo) -> capsule

Tags: python, c++, python-3.6, pybind11, pybinding

I want to call a C++ function from Python using `pybind11`. The C++ function is declared as:

```cpp
void *getimage(GstPadProbeInfo *info)
```

In Python, I am calling `getimage` with:

```python
image = example.getimage(info)
```

where the Python type of `info` is `gi.repository.GstPadProbeInfo`. When
when I run the code I get:

```
incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:    1. (arg0: _GstPadProbeInfo) -> capsule
```

How can I resolve this?